# How do I edit an XML file in Emacs with tag autocompletion from a known XSD schema?

Tags: nxml, xml, xml-schema

I'd like to use Emacs for XML editing.

A long, long time ago I recall using pSGML to do that.

Now that I've returned to Emacs I'd like to have tag autocompletion and easy navigation in XML files. Unfortunately, pSGML has fallen into disrepair and I have to make do with nXML.

Comment: This is ...confusing... All this use of outdated external tools...

Comment: The more I look at it, the more I see the weak point - adequate transformation of the XSD into a decent RNC. `auto-complete-nxml-mode` did the trick of autocompletion, although I had to search a bit. Will write up an answer if no one else comes with a tutorial...

Comment: Regarding "auto-completion", installing `company-mode` should be all there is to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the hardest part has to be done outside Emacs.

- Install `auto-complete` and `auto-complete-nxml` from MELPA (easy).
- Note: don't use `genrnc` from MELPA 'cause it does not fit the bill...
- Ensure that `xsltproc` is installed on the system (easy for Linux/Unix/OSX users).
- Add the following customization into the user's `~/.emacs` file (easy):

```
 (require 'auto-complete-nxml)
 ;; Keystroke to popup help about something at point.
 (setq auto-complete-nxml-popup-help-key "C-:")
 ;; Keystroke to toggle on/off automatic completion.
 (setq auto-complete-nxml-toggle-automatic-key "C-c C-t")
```

- Get the XSD schema for the XML format in use (easy)
- Convert the XSD file into a RELAX NG Compact format file usable by nXML (**hard**!)

---

**Approach #1**:

1. get [XSDtoRNG](https://github.com/epiasini/xsdtorng) converter stylesheet (easy)
2. run `xsltproc XSDtoRNG.xsl MySchema.xsd > MySchema.rng` (easy)
3. get [RngToRnc](https://web.archive.org/web/20070622050100/http://www.pantor.com/RngToRnc-1_4.tgz) (mostly future-proof)
4. run `xsltproc RngToRncClassic.xsl MySchema.rng > MySchema.rnc` (easy)

---

**Approach #2**:

1. find `trang` and `rngconv` utilities
2. ...work in progress...

---

- Load the XML file into Emacs. Major mode should be nXML, minor mode should be AC.
- XML > Set Schema > File ... and choose `MySchema.rnc`.
- Manually edit `MySchema.rnc` when Emacs complains (**hard**!), save it, and repeat the previous step.
- Use autocompletion (`ESC-TAB`) when needed.